# Why for loop is not looping sequently through permissions in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

i hope you are i good health. Recently i got my some hands on jetpack compose and tried to build a small app for gaining experience. Here is the problem that i'm facing below is the code :

```
 for (permission in permissions){
            val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = permission.permission)
            if (!permissionState.status.isGranted) {
                AccessInfo(
                    accessDetails = permission,
                    isPopupEnabled = false,
                    onDetailLinkClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    onPopUpButtonClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    onPermissionResult = { isGranted ->
                        if (isGranted) {

                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
```

The above code works fine it checks for the all permission that are provided in list if those are granted or not if not then ui is generated by passing the permission so user can allow the permission. The code works very well even if the user allow or deny any permission by going to the app setting while the app is running. IT working fine. THe problem is if user denied more than one permission the ui is created again and again over each other. What i want it should be sequential.

Note: I tried all AI tools they are not hitting the correct answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make use of recompositions. Introduce a `permissionIndex` variable that stores the index of the permission that is currently checked. For each permission that already is granted, just increase the index, which will cause a recomposition. If a permission is not granted, then wait before increase the index until the user responded to the permission request dialog.

Whenever the user returns to the App, reset the `permissionIndex` to 0, this will check all permissions again.

Have a look at the following sample code:

```
var permissionIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val lifecycleState by lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentStateFlow.collectAsState()
LaunchedEffect(lifecycleState) {
     if (lifecycleState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        // This code will be executed whenever the App comes to foreground again
        permissionIndex = 0
     }
}

if (permissionIndex < permissions.size) {
    val permission = permissions.get(permissionIndex)
    val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = permission.permission)
    if (!permissionState.status.isGranted) {
        AccessInfo(
            accessDetails = permission,
            isPopupEnabled = false,
            onDetailLinkClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            onPopUpButtonClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            onPermissionResult = { isGranted ->
                permissionIndex++;
            }
        )
    } else {
        permissionIndex++;
    }

}
```

You might need to add the following dependency:

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.7.0")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I alredy have tried this one. There is an issue suppose ther are three permissions user allow two permissions and we are at third permission index right now. now from there imagine that user go to setting and deny the first permission manully. How would you handle that ? Beacuse you are third index. from there i want tht if uyser do so then after alowing the third one it should again jump to the denied pemrission again.